# usage: command not found

Tags: bash, shell, command-line-arguments, sh

I have a file parsing option flags from command line input, and if you pass in `-h`, it's giving an error.

```
h)  
    usage
    exit 1
;;
```

returns: `usage: command not found`

Does anybody know what’s going on here? I've found many examples that use `usage`, so I would think it should work. I can’t seem to find any relevant info on it searching google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are missing is a function definition of usage:

```
function usage {
    cat <<-USAGE
         Now you can define your usage here
         take as many lines as you want. When
         you finish, just put "USAGE" on a line
         by itself.
    USAGE
}
```

Put this BEFORE the call of `usage`. Remember that the line with `USAGE` must be preceded only by tabs.

Comment: In case it's not clear to the readers of this answer, the `<<-` heredoc will strip of leading **tab** characters, not any arbitrary whitespace. ref: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents

Comment: I mentioned that it _must be preceded only by tabs_, but you're right it's still not clear. I like doing it this way because it's easier to provide multiple line usage instructions.

Answer (score 4):

You need add to your shell script *before* you call the `usage` the next:

```
usage() {
    echo  "$0: some help text"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Those working examples define a function called `usage` in their source.

As you see, it gets called, when you provide the `-h` flag.

The usual reason behind moving it to a function is that

- it doesn't clutter the code
- can be reused, e.g. when you provide invalid arguments.

Answer (score 1):

`usage` is not a command, but the common name for a custom shell function you supply that outputs usage information for your script.